# SAS Put value from array if find value from array

Tags: arrays, sas

My code and problem:

```
data Scinamy;
   input Description $20. ;
   datalines;                      
New old Active
New Active Old
ANother record
Records with Gold
Value with Gold
;

   Data Scinamy1;
   set Scinamy;

array lista[3] $ _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');

do i = LBound(lista) To HBound(lista);
    if find(upcase(lista{i}),upcase(Description)) > 0 then
        do;
            AA= upcase(lista{i});
            leave;
        end;
    else
        do;
            AA = 'not contain';
        end;
end;
run;
```

This code put for all records only first value from array.
How I can mapping all value from array and put value from array if find in string suitable value?
Best regards!

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample input and output data. If you find multiple matching words in `Description`, do you want to capture that in extra rows or in extra columns?

Comment: Now you have added the input data in the form of a data step (well done), please also show the output data you want (as also mentioned by @user667489), based on the input data you have supplied.

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than one of the terms in your LISTA array is found?  Do you want the first? The last?  Do you want a space delimited string of all found values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any sample data it's hard to tell but I believe the problem is that variable AA is overwritten by subsequent array values. If you want to see the value from each column in array outputted then you have to create an array with same size as Lista to hold the distinct values. Something like this

```
Data Scinamy1;
 set Scinamy;

 array lista[3] $ _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');
 array new[3] $ AA1 - AA3;

 do i = LBound(lista) To HBound(lista);
   if find(upcase(Description),strip(upcase(lista{i}))) > 0 then
      do;
        new[i]= upcase(lista{i});
        leave;
     end;
  else
     do;
        new[i] = 'not contain';
     end;
 end;
run;
```

If you add some data though it would be easier to solve your problem in case your program is a bit different from what you actually want.

I see you are looking for Active, Gold and Prime in description not otherwise. So I updated your find function.

Comment: John Doe, thank you for answer.
Unfortunately it does not work. I added example data, your code did that my - for AA1-AA3 sets everywhere 'not contain'

Comment: I updated the code because your find function was doing the wrong thing. Let me know if the result is what you expect.

Comment: Something works! But, for rows one and five. Although rows 2 and 4 have string active in description - code not found this values. Why?

Comment: I modified to use the strip function which helps ignore leading and trailing blanks during the search process.

Comment: Thanks you John :)

Answer (score 0):

I add example data:

```
data Scinamy;
   input Description $20. ;
   datalines;                      
New old Active
New Active Old
ANother record
Records with Gold
Value with Gold
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that `FINDW()` is a better function to use for this type of search. It will avoid finding the strings when they are just contained in larger words.  You can use the modifiers to make it case insensitive and trim blanks.

I like to use `SPIT` as the modifiers. `SP` will add spaces and punctuation as delimiters and `IT` will ignore case and trim blanks.

Set the value you want for failure AFTER your DO loop.

```
data Scinamy;
   input Description $30. ;
datalines;                      
New old Active
New Active Old
Another record subprime
Records with gold
Value with Gold
Prime Gold Active
;

data Scinamy1;
  set Scinamy;
  array lista(3) $8 _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');
  length AA $30 ;
  do i = 1 to dim(lista);
    if findw(Description,lista(i),,'spit') then AA=catx(' ',AA,lista(i));
  end;
  if missing(AA) then AA='Not Found';
  drop i;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have one additionaly question. 
How I can set another table on places dictionary in array?

```
 array lista(3) $8 _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');
```

Instead ('Active','Gold','Prime') put values from another table?